# Unable to connect to ActionCable on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to get a Rails 5.0 app with ActionCable deployed on Elastic Beanstalk running Nginx and Puma.

In `.ebextensions/nginx.config` I have the following:

`location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
}`

and in `config/environments/production.rb`

`config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://####.####.com', /http:\/\/####.*/ ]`

After deploying the app to the Elastic Beanstalk environment I end up with this error in the Chrome console:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://####.####.com/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

I've tried following the advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536926/actioncable-on-aws-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code) but end up getting this error instead:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://####.####.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

This is what my [`.ebextensions/nginx.config`](https://gist.github.com/MarceloAlves/cd15229c9fd204b56b97aeb910462ecf) file looks like currently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the connection was being killed at the Elastic Load Balancer. ELB Listeners were set to HTTP and needed to be TCP.

Comment: Would you mind about sharing some additional information?

In line: proxy_pass `http://backend`; should I change to `http://my_backend_host_etc.com` ?

Comment: @PaspRuby for my setup I have this in the `nginx.conf`:

```upstream backend {
        server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
      }```

So the `proxy_pass` line is referencing that upstream value and points directly to the running puma server

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, getting `WebSocket connection to 'ws://####.####.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404` What do you have for listeners @MarceloAlves? I have this: Listener 1: Port 80 HTTP, Instance port 80 Instance protocol HTTP; Listener 2: Port 443 HTTPS, Instance port 80 Instance protocol HTTP.

Comment: @Jack Hey there. Unfortunately we stopped using websockets long ago and upgraded to the newer Application Load Balancer which reset the listeners to HTTP. I believe in order for websockets to work on the Classic LB it needs to be set to TCP